# Imap IDLE in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, imap, zend-mail

I am searching for the [IMAP IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) function in the Zend Framework. I would either like to know whether it is integrated or if it could be done. I have read that the IlohaMail library seems to have implemented the function - at least in a modified version used in roundcube.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework supports issuing the ["NOOP" - No operation - command](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Mail/Protocol/Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap.html#noop) to the IMAP servers to renew the connection.

According to http://www.isode.com/whitepapers/imap-idle.html, this resembles the IMAP IDLE process.

Comment: Well, not really.  Sending regular `NOOP` commands is client pull of notifications; `IDLE` engages server push.