# IMAP IDLE is using ZEND PHP Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, imap

I found similar question here

[Imap IDLE in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435299/imap-idle-in-zend-framework)

but link given there is broken and that answer don't describe about IMAP IDLE in zend.

and ticket here
http://zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-11216

Does PHP ZEND support IDLE or not ?